# RegOpenKeyEx fails on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

Hi I'm trying to read a registry value that gives me the path to firefox.exe.
This is stored under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox 3.0.10\bin
```

(the version number can be found somewhere else)

But I cant seem to get RegOpenKeyEx to return ERROR_SUCCESS for anything under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
```

so this test fails:

```
if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("\\SOFTWARE"),0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE,&keyHandle) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

while this test passes:

```
if(RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,TEXT("\\Shell"),0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE,&keyHandle) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: What is the value of GetLastError() immediately after RegOpenKeyEx fails?

Comment: Don't check GetLastError(), this function doesn't set it. The error code is in the return value, so assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following code failed on my machine with the error code 161, which means "bad path" (look it up in winerror.h):

```
long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("SOFTWARE"),
                      0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hk );
```

I then changed the call to RegOpenKeyEx to use "SOFTWARE" (note no leading slashes) and it worked:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main() {
    HKEY hk;

    // Notice that it's SOFTWARE instead of \\SOFTWARE:
    long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("SOFTWARE"),
                      0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hk );
    if ( n == ERROR_SUCCESS ) {
        cout << "OK" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed with value " << n << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx, that was it! I think that it might be caused by that SOFTWARE is saved in a separate file (got this info from wikipedia though), and isnt a folder like Shell is in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Comment: What to do with the `hk` to really READ it?