# C++ get data from registry key

Tags: c++, windows, registry

Hello I know this sounds silly but I really failed this time.

I m making application in C++ that will show users configuration. Most informations I get from registry key ex. 
Proccessor name is located at

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0]
 Key is:  `ProcessorNameString`
```

How can get data from that key in C++ and get give it to variable?

Comment: Make a web search for WinAPI C++ Registry and go from there (you should find lots of examples online)

Answer (score 0):

Google C++ read HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Find something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820846/regopenkeyex-fails-on-hkey-local-machine)

Try something like this:

```
HKEY hk;

long n = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,TEXT("HARDWARE\\Description\\"),
                  0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hk );
```

When that doesn't fully work, look up `RegOpenKeyEx`.