# Why can't I open my registry Key

Tags: c, winapi

First time asking a question so hope I'm doing it right...

I'm trying to write a small program to change the reg key for the home page of internet explorer but each time I run it I'm getting the error that the key location open was unsuccessful. Any ideas why? (Tried running in admin)

```
//this string array will be the value for the new home page (w/ null termination)
char newHomePage[] = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwJ_LgYYvpU \0";
HKEY homePageKey = NULL; //handle for the key once opened


//Open reg key we wish to change, if this fails then abort 

//reg key for home page 
if (RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &homePageKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Key location open successful \n");
    if (RegSetValueExW(homePageKey, L"Start Page", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)&newHomePage, sizeof(char)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Key changed in registry \n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Key not changed in registry \n");
        printf("Error %u ", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
    }
    RegCloseKey(homePageKey);
}
else
{
    printf("Error: %u \n", (unsigned int)GetLastError());
    printf("Key location open UNsuccessful \n");
    system("pause");
    RegCloseKey(homePageKey);
    return 0;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: I suggest breaking the first if statement into two lines so that you can inspect the return value of `RegOpenKeyExW()`. This might give you a clue as to the issue.

Comment: Why are you calling `GetLastError`? The documentation makes no mention of that. It says: *If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h.*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegOpenKeyEx fails on HKEY\_LOCAL\_MACHINE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820846/regopenkeyex-fails-on-hkey-local-machine)

Comment: Do some debugging. Print the values of the variables.

Comment: I guess it's because the key name starts with a backslash

Comment: As a side note, if I were to open the URL (which I did not) of your example, would I get the impression that you try to promote something? Not to say spam.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry, the URL was just some dummy data used for posting the question online (it was just an open song that I had playing on youtube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. Do NOT include a leading slash when specifying a subkey to `RegCreateKeyEx()` or `RegOpenKeyEx()`.
2. You are passing your URL as an ANSI string to a function that expects a Unicode string. And you are specifying the wrong data size.
3. You are getting error codes from `GetLastError()`, but the Registry API doesn't use `SetLastError()` to report errors.  Error codes are returned in function return values instead.

Try this instead:

```
//this string array will be the value for the new home page (w/ null termination)
const wchar_t newHomePage[] = L"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwJ_LgYYvpU\0";
HKEY homePageKey = NULL; //handle for the key once opened

//Open reg key we wish to change, if this fails then abort
//reg key for home page
LONG lResult = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &homePageKey);
if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Key location open successful \n");
    lResult = RegSetValueExW(homePageKey, L"Start Page", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)newHomePage, sizeof(newHomePage)); // or (lstrlenW(newHomePage)+1)*sizeof(wchar_t)
    if (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Key changed in registry \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Key not changed in registry \n");
        printf("Error %ld \n", lResult);
    }
    RegCloseKey(homePageKey);
}
else
{
    printf("Key location open UNsuccessful \n");
    printf("Error: %ld \n", lResult);
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```